# How to get 1 value from DAX FILTER?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have Users table containing user_email, user_name, user_category.

The following DAX filter returns a table:

```
FILTER(Users,[User_Email] = userprincipalname())
```

I want to get the user_category.

1 approach is `SELECTEDCOLUMNS( FILTER(Users,[User_Email] = userprincipalname()), "User_category", [User_Category] )`. This returns the result as a column.

Is there any alternate approach to return just 1 value? For example:

```
SELECTEDVALUE ( SELECTEDCOLUMNS( FILTER(Users,[User_Email] = userprincipalname()), "User_category", [User_Category] ) )
```

OR

```
VALUES ( SELECTEDCOLUMNS( FILTER(Users,[User_Email] = userprincipalname()), "User_category", [User_Category] ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAXX` on the table generated by `FILTER`.

```
MAXX(
       FILTER(Users,[User_Email] = userprincipalname()),
       [User_Category]
)
```

Comment: The last argument should be [User_Category] in stead of [User_Email], right?

Comment: Yep, calculation fixed.

Comment: In there anything like FIRST that given the first value instead of MAXX?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CALCULATE assuming you don't expect there to be multiple values to choose from (if there are, this will return a blank).

```
CALCULATE (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Users[User_Category] ),
    FILTER ( Users, Users[User_Email] = userprincipalname() )
)
```

Comment: In terms of performance, is it better to use your approach (CALCULATE) or the one from the other answer (MAXX)?

Comment: As a general rule, CALCULATE with filters tends to be faster than using iterators but I doubt there's much noticeable difference for something this simple. If you're particularly concerned about performance, you should probably only filter on a single column rather than a whole table. E.g. `KEEPFILTERS ( Users[User_Email] = userprincipalname() )` instead of the FILTER argument.

Comment: Is your suggestion to use column because of the fact that using table name results in the table expansion?

Comment: "There are few golden rules in the DAX world, but one for sure is: never filter a table when you can filter a column. In fact, filtering a table requires you to understand expanded tables and their behavior when you use them as a filter parameter in CALCULATE."  Conclusion from [Context Transition and Expanded Tables](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/context-transition-and-expanded-tables/)

Comment: "The filter table is usually the “easy” way to write a valid complex filter expression, but it could have a large granularity for the FILTER iterator and a higher cost for the filter itself in CALCULATE, considering the related cost of an expanded table in a filter argument."  Conclusion from [Filter Arguments in CALCULATE](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/)